# Group by of dataframe with average of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am really new to python..just a week ago started learning it. I have a query and hope you guys can help me to solve it. Thanks in advance..!!

I have data in below format.

```
Date        Product Price   Discount
1/1/2020    A   17,490  30  
1/1/2020    B   34,990  21
1/1/2020    C   20,734  11  
1/2/2020    A   16,884  26  
1/2/2020    B   26,990  40  
1/2/2020    C   17,936  10  
1/3/2020    A   16,670  36  
1/3/2020    B   12,990  13  
1/3/2020    C   30,990  43
```

I want to take the average of discount column for each date and just have 2 columns.. It aint working out.. :(

```
Date        AVG_Discount
1/1/2020    x %
1/2/2020    y %
1/3/2020    z %
```

What I have tried doing is below.. As I said, I am novice in Python so approach might be incorrect.. Need guidance guys.. TIA

```
mean_col=df.groupby(df['time'])['discount'].mean()
df=df.set_index(['time'])
df['mean_col']=mean_col
df=df.reset_index()
```

Comment: isnt just `df.groupby(df['time'])['discount'].mean().reset_index()` works for your case?

Comment: indeed it does.. i am still undergoing basics of pandas so all functions and options are a bit tricky.. but this helps a lot.. Thanks..!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `df.groupby(df['time'])['discount'].mean()` Is already returning series with `time` as index.
- All you need to do is just use `reset_index` function on this.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(df['time'])['discount'].mean().reset_index()
```

- As Quang Hoang Suggested in comments. You can also pass `as_index=False` to groupby.

Comment: `groupby(..., as_index=False)` saves you from `reset_index()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have read your DataFrame from a text file,
e.g. CSV, but with separator other than a comma.

Run `df.info()` and I assume that you got result something like below:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Date        9 non-null object
Product     9 non-null object
Price       9 non-null object
Discount    9 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
```

Note that *Date*, *Product* and *Price* columns are of *object* type
(actually, a **string**). This remark is especially importoant in case of
*Price* column, because to compte *mean* you should have source column
as a **number** (not a string).

So first you should convert *Date* and *Price* columns to proper types
(*datetime* and *float*). To do it run:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.Price = df.Price.str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Run `df.info()` again and now the result should be:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Date        9 non-null datetime64[ns]
Product     9 non-null object
Price       9 non-null float64
Discount    9 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
```

And now you can compute the mean discount, running:

```
df.groupby('Date').Discount.mean()
```

For your data I got:

```
Date
2020-01-01    20.666667
2020-01-02    25.333333
2020-01-03    30.666667
Name: Discount, dtype: float64
```

Note that your code sample contains the following errors:

- Argument of *groupby* is the column name (or a list of column names), so:

  - `df` between parentheses is not needed,
  - instead of *time* you should write *Date* (you have no *time* column).
- Your *Discount* column is written starting with **capital** *D*.